# Post XML Data to aspx page and reditect to the page from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, vb.net

I need to post some xml data  to a different aspx page  and redirect to the same page. 
I tried the following code it does post to the page sucessfully but i need to redirect to the same page with posted data

```
         req.Method = "POST";       
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";     
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
        writer.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
        writer.Close();
        rsp = req.GetResponse();
```

could you guys help me with this?

Thank in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

[Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) should work:

```
rsp.Redirect(url);
```

Comment: Hi Joey  the rsp above is  WebResponse  not the Response object. can you tell me how to do the post xml from response.redirect

Comment: `Server.Transfer(url); // System.Web.Server` might work better than

Comment: i need to post and redirect at same time    how can we post xml from above code

Comment: Do you just want that xml available when that other page loads? If so, so this: Session["xml"] = xml.toString(); Server.Transfer(url); .. then in the other page's on_Load: string xml = Session["xml"];

Comment: Thats  good way!!  however  pages are in two different projects  so i am not able to us the session is there any other way ?

Comment: Geez, um... Do the post, then Server.Transfer(url + "?xmlId=1234"); When the other project gets the post, store it in Session["1234"]; Then page_load on the new page: string id = HttpContext.Current.Request["xmlId"]; string xml = Session["1234"];

Answer (score -1):

What you're asking for is impossible in it's current form, this is due to the way HTTP works.

When you use POST you simply send data to the server, and collect the result.  If you then want to show the user that page, you'll have to make a new request by the way of GET.

The easiest way to do this in asp.net is using `Response.Redirect()`.

Comment: Sorry, my comment didn't post.  The downvote is in regards to "what you're asking for is impossible..."  He is asking how to post data and do a redirect.  There are at least 3 different viable ways of doing this.  You even mention one in your post...

Comment: @Chris - Sorry I meant "in its current state" this is impossible

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in its current state".  All the OP has to do is add a response.redirect to the end of the code block he has...  Could you clarify?